# Difference between two combinatorics notations

Tags: combinatorics

My prof defined that for $ n \in $ Positive numbers. Let $ [n] :=  \left\{ 1,2,3,...,n \right\}$

I wonder if there are any differences between ${n \choose 2}$ and ${[n] \choose 2}$ ?

**In short, I want to know the meaning of ${[n] \choose 2}$**

Because I am working on a problem that asks to prove the identity:
(Have to use bijective proof)

## #$Comp_k(n)$ = #${[n-1] \choose k-1}$

where #$Comp_k(n)$ is the number of ways of composition of n into k parts.

I don't know if I can replace  #${[n-1] \choose k-1}$ with #${n-1 \choose k-1}$...

Comment: # means number of ways counts the following

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I know the definition of composition, but I am not sure what does the [  ] symbol do in this case, which is the last question on my post. Thanks anyways!

My professor wants us to construct a bijection to show that the identity is true, but I am stuck with the notation [ ] in the question

Comment: The main difference is that the second does not have a  meaning.

Comment: Since you know the definition of compositions (whether weak or not, you did not say), and you surely know the definition of binomial coefficient, compare the two values and see what $[n-1]$ must mean in context to make the notation work.

Comment: Can I simply prove #$Comp_k(n)$ = #${n-1 \choose k-1}$ instead of proving #$Comp_k(n)$ = #${[n-1] \choose k-1}$ ? @hardmath Thanks.

Comment: @bof Oh! I see your point. Yes, I also think #6 = 6. I'd ask my professor tmrw and I'll let you know :)

Comment: @bof That's what my prof defined the [ ]. I meant I don't understand what does [ ] symbol do in the identity. That's why I asked if I could simply take away the [ ] and continue proving the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[n]$ is a common notation for the set consisting of the first $n$ positive integers.

If $S$ is a set, then $\binom Sk$ is a common notation for the set of all $k$-element subsets of $S.$

If $S$ is an $n$-element set, $n$ and $k$ nonnegative integers, then $\text#\binom Sk=\binom nk=\binom{\text#S}k$.

In particular, if $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, then $\binom{[n-1]}{k-1}$ is the set of all $k-1$-element subsets of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, and $\text#\binom{[n-1]}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$

I guess the intent of the problem is to have you prove that
$$\text#\operatorname{Comp}_k(n)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
and writing the right hand side in the form $\text#\binom{[n-1]}{k-1}$
was supposed to be a **hint**, i.e.:

> **Hint.** It's the number of ways you can choose $k-1$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}.$

Comment: How about for the identity #Comp(n) = #($2^{[n-1]}$). How can I interpret the right hand side?

Comment: $2^S$ is a common notation for the set of all subsets of a set $S$ (haven't these notations been defined in your class?), so $\text#2^S=2^{\text#S},$ and $2^{[n-1]}$ is the set of **all** subsets of $\{1,\dots,n-1\},$ i.e., summing the $k$-element sets over all values of $k.$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is an integer,
then $n-1 = [n-1]$,
so the two are exactly the same.

Comment: No, $[n]$ is not the floor function $\lfloor n\rfloor$  here; as defined on the first line of the question, $[n]$ is the set consisting of the first $n$ positive integers.

Comment: @bof Thanks bof, I think you are correct.